# How to find the gradient $\nabla_W \left( u^T_1 W \left( W E W^T + \lambda I \right)^{-1} W^{T} u_2 \right)$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I am struggling to find the gradient

$$\nabla_W \left( u^T_1 W \left( W E W^T + \lambda I \right)^{-1} W^{T} u_2 \right)$$

where $I \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the identity matrix, $\lambda > 0$, $E \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix, $u_1,u_2$ are two vectors. I tried using the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) but the best approximation for a solution for this problem is Eq. 127, which is not exactly the prototype of this expression. Would be grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\lr#1{\l(#1\r)}
\def\s#1{\operatorname{Sym}\lr{#1}}
\def\t#1{\operatorname{Tr}\lr{#1}}
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$First, define the trace/Frobenius product and the $\tt{Sym()}$ function
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}Y_{ij} \;=\; \t{XY^T} \\
\s{X} &= \frac 12\lr{X+X^T}
}$$
For typing convenience, define the symmetric matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
A &= \s{u_1u_2^T} &\implies\quad A=A^T =\s{A} \\
B &= \lr{WEW^T+\lambda I}^{-1} &\implies\quad B=B^T = \s{B} \\
& &\implies\quad dB = -2B\,\s{dW\,EW^T} B \\
}$$
Write the function using the above definitions.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A:WBW^T \\
d\phi &= A:dW\,BW^T + A:WB\,dW^T + A:W\,\c{dB}\,W^T \\
 &= AWB:dW + BW^TA:dW^T + A:W\,\c{\l(-2B\,\s{dW\,EW^T} B\r)}\,W^T \\
 &= AWB:dW + AWB :dW - 2BW^TAWB:\s{dW\,EW^T} \\
 &= 2AWB:dW - 2BW^TAWB:dW\,EW^T \\
 &= 2\l(AWB - BW^TAWBWE\r):dW \\
\grad{\phi}{W} &= 2\l(AWB - BW^TAWBWE\r) \\\\
}$$

---

Note that the transpose and cyclic properties of the trace function allows the terms in a Frobenius product to be rearranged in several different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= Y:X \;=\; Y^T:X^T \\
XY:Z &= X:ZY^T = Y:X^TZ \\
}$$
The Frobenius product also interacts nicely with the $\tt{Sym()}$ function
$$\eqalign{
X:\s{Y} &= \s{X}:Y \\
}$$